# Html tag displayed after submit in CKEditor Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor, rich-text-editor

I really confused using CKEditor, I tried to write an article in CKEditor
for example I've written `Hello world` with **Bold** and align left.
but when I submit, that appears like this

> `<p style="text-align: right;"><strong>hello world</strong></p>`

I've read in some forum, for remove the HTML tags can use `raw`

it work but the article that have been stored in the database still have the HTML tags

some have suggested, before save the article to database can use **sanitize gem**  but I don't understand how to use this gem

my question is

is there any way to remove **html tags** before saving to the database and display ?

is there an option in the settings ckeditor about this problem? or I missed something?

thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve your text with specific styles defined by any html editor, you have to store text with html tags in db. 
"sanitize gem" is for removing html tags and retrieving pure texts from them. Just like opposite of "raw" or "html_safe" actions.

Answer (score 0):

for example, if you have a post.body that is full of html code
 such as

```
 <p style="text-align: right;"><strong>hello world</strong></p>
```

you can use if use raw(post.body) to display only the text "hello world"

However that didnt work for me, so I called the method that raw() calls directly to get what I need:

```
post.body.to_s.html_safe
```